# How can I get the id I just added?

Tags: php

I have 2 table like this

- cart table, cart detail table
  [order table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxIOq.png)

[order-detail table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkynM.png)

I want when the user order is successful, the table ORDER will be added to the new data, and then I will get the id of the newly added to add data to the ORDER_DETAIL table so how can I get the id of the newly added column of the order table at that moment?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: By the way, after you update you need to write new query with select order with last insert row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please do not use external sites to link images, as they may disappear in the future. Just list your fields in here, if needed.

Comment: tks you guys for help me, I finded the answer :D .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MySQLs `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function to retrieve the ID of the last inserted row in a table:

```sql
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

If this is not what you meant, please clarify your question by editing your post.